# In blogger API, what does quotaUser parameter do?

Tags: google-api, blogger

In blogger API what is the meaning of **quotaUser** parameter and it is mentioned that **"Must not exceed 40 characters"** do we need to include **quotaUser=40** to our search query? or how it is effect to our quota limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quotaUser is an optional paramater used by all of the discovery services apis.  It is basicly used to denote a user when you are making requests.

All of the APIs are quota based and each user is limited to X number of requests per 100 seconds.   By default users are denoted by IP address this way a single user can not make to many requests from a single machine at the same time and flood the server.

Using the QuotaUser parameter allows you to send a random string to Google that would denote different users.  This is useful when you are running in batch on a server where all the requests are coming from the same IP address but you are running the requests on behalf of different users.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So I wanted to know that, when I am going to create simple blog app by using blogger API, do I need to use those parameters?

Comment: nope not unless this is running on a server and your going to have thousands of calls i wouldn't bother.